# Raise an error to the user via Model Admin & DataObject::onBeforeDelete()

Tags: silverstripe, modeladmin

Given I'm using Model Admin to manage a Customer DataObject and I have code like this, taken from the SilverStripe docs:

```
public function onBeforeDelete() {
    if ($this->Orders()->Count() > 0) {
        user_error("Cannot delete a Customer with Orders", E_USER_ERROR);
        exit();
    }
    parent::onBeforeDelete();
}
```

When I try to delete a Customer with Orders via Model Admin all I get is a JavaScript alert that says "An error occured while fetching data from the server. Please try again later" and a notification on the top right of

```
Error at line 42 of /var/www/mysite/code/dataobjects/Customer.php
```

How do I get a nice message to come back to Model Admin saying "Cannot delete a Customer with Orders"?

Comment: What code is present at line 42 of Customer.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public function canDelete($member=null) {
    if ($this->Orders()->Count() > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return parent::canDelete($member);
```

}

This will remove the delete button altogether, but you'd have to make it clear to your users why in another way.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the best solution

Comment: LiteralField::create('DeleteButtonHelp', '<div class="some-pretty-class">This is why I cannot see the delete button.</div>');

Answer (score 4):

As well as overloading the validate function, you can throw a `ValidationException`.

```
public function onBeforeDelete() {
    if ($this->Orders()->Count() > 0) {
        throw new ValidationException("Cannot delete a Customer with Orders");
    }
    parent::onBeforeDelete();
}
```

`ValidationException` is trapped by the form processing code and should show the error as one of those pop-up message in the top-right.

Answer (score 3):

You can show a message in the CMS default error message style on the right top corner. The simple trick is to return an error header, which the ajax call knows to handle.

```
public function onBeforeDelete() {
   if ($this->Orders()->Count() > 0) {
     header("HTTP/1.1 403 Sorry you can not delete a customer with orders");
        exit;
    }
    parent::onBeforeDelete();
 }
```

If you use such messages more, the best way is to put a function in a custom siteconfig extension class and call it each time to handle the situation. For example, put the following code in one of your common functions file or in a class like class SiteConfigExtension extends DataExtension.

```
public function popupCMSError($message='The action is not allowed', $errorCode=403)
{
        header("HTTP/1.1 $errorCode $message");
        exit;
}
```

Then, you can always call it in situations like yours or for any other purposes in the following way (if in siteconfig class for example):

```
singleton('SiteConfig')->popupCMSError("Sorry your custom message here");
```

Note: I used HTTP error 403 here for illustration only. You can use other headers as well. The same style is used in Silverstripe Framework core to display CMS errors.